# Edit with Javascript a cell of a Primefaces DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a non-editable DataTable built with PrimeFaces. The table is initially filled with values obtained through a Bean's getter:

```
<p:dataTable var="lndClient" value="#{clientBean.model}" rowKey="#{lndClient.stringId}">
```

After the table is loaded, I need to update some cells through Javascript. The reason for that is that I am using [cometD](http://cometd.org/), a Ajax Push Technology pattern that uses Javascript-JQuery on the client side.

I know that I can update a cell by using something like

```
$('td#id').html("value");
```

but my problem is that I have no clue of what is the id of my cell(s). Looking at the html generated, I see that the rows are:

```
<tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd"><td><div class="ui-dt-c"><a id="centerTabView:accordion:j_idt18:j_idt19:1:j_idt22" ...>
...
<tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even"><td><div class="ui-dt-c"><a id="centerTabView:accordion:j_idt18:j_idt19:2:j_idt22" ...>
```

Indeed, the row identifier is there, although inside a `td` tag. And the other columns are:

```
<td><div class="ui-dt-c">...</div></td>
```

So, my question is: how can I identify a cell in a PrimeFaces DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible for you to refer to cells by column index and row id, you can use `rowStyleClass` attribute of `p:dataTable`.

For instance if you set it as `rowStyleClass="#{lndClient.stringId}"`, you will be able to refer to 3rd column of row with stringId `xyz` by something like `$('tr.xyz td:first-child+td+td')` - I am sure you can come up with a better selector.

Comment: This works indeed!. Let's wait a little while to see if somebody comes with what you call "a better selector"...

Comment: @perissf Somewhat handier alternative is `$('tr.xyz td:nth-child(3)')` but there could be even better selector.